# Why can't I concatenate int data in C#?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C#. I'm currently trying to concatenate int data and using the Math square root function, but after running the program, it produces an error.

The code are as follows.

```
using System;

namespace NewProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type any number");
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int square_root = Math.Sqrt(number);
            Console.WriteLine("$The square root of {square_root} is " , square_root);

        }
    }
}
```

```
C:\Users\ajmal\Documents\Learn C#\New Project\Program.cs(13,31): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) [C:\Users\ajmal\Documents\Learn C#\New Project\N
ew Project.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

Any tips and help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you need to use a double to hold square_root instead of an int. That, or cast it to an int. And if you want to concatenate the value, use 'number' for the interpolated value and append square_root to the string.

Comment: The problem is not to do with concatenation but you will then hit another problem with concatenation. After you fix the "double into int" problem, make the last line of your program one of these: `Console.WriteLine($"The square root of {number} is {square_root}");` or `Console.WriteLine("The square root of {0} is {1}", number, square_root);` - at the moment you're  mixing the two approaches

Answer (score 6):

The compiler message tells:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

It even gives you the location of the error:

> New Project\Program.cs(13,31)

Line 13, position 31

If you look there, not very far you should find this line:

```cs
int square_root = Math.Sqrt(number);
```

If you look that the `Math.Sqrt` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=net-6.0), you'll see that `Math.Sqrt` returns a double.

Here is the signature from the documentation:

> `public static double Sqrt (double d);`

So you try to put a `double` into an `int` (the type of your `square_root` variable), which is only possible with an explicit cast, hence the compiler message.

To fix this (supposing you want to keep a non integer value for the square root) simply correct the line with

`double square_root = Math.Sqrt(number);`

or you can even let the compiler do the work by leveraging the `var` keyword:

`var square_root = Math.Sqrt(number);`

Additional remarks:

The `Math.Sqrt` signature shows that a `double` is needed as parameter, but you pass an `int`. This is not a problem since the compiler can do an implicit conversion from an int to a double.

There will also be an error on the following line (without even considering the meaning of what you write).

```cs
Console.WriteLine("$The square root of {square_root} is " , square_root);
```

To concatenate strings, you can use several techniques, like composite formating and string interpolation. It seems you mix both synthax on this line.

See the [string interpolation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

an example of both methods taken from the documentaion:

```cs
string name = "Mark";
var date = DateTime.Now;

// Composite formatting:
Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}! Today is {1}, it's {2:HH:mm} now.", name, date.DayOfWeek, date);
// String interpolation:
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}! Today is {date.DayOfWeek}, it's {date:HH:mm} now.");
// Both calls produce the same output that is similar to:
// Hello, Mark! Today is Wednesday, it's 19:40 now.
```

Comment: This is not a Math or type related issue. I think it is just the format `$` is inside the `"`. Simple fix could be:    `Console.WriteLine($"The square root of {number} is {square_root}");`

Comment: Well, there is also an error on the `Console.Writeline` line.
It should be something like `Console.WriteLine("$The square root of {0} is {1} " , number, square_root);` or `Console.WriteLine($"The square root of {number} is {square_root}");` using string interpolation. But this doesn't change the fact that there was first a type error.